# How to fix mysqli updating wrong value in db?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm setting up a password change script for php. All variables are in the function updatePasswordInDatabase($password, $email) { ..}. 
I've triple checked that the values that the function receives are correct. 
For the insertion in the database (mysql) i'm using mysqli with prepared statements.

For example, I'm inputting:
                                                                          `$2y$12$X/jIjlqpWfSSMg70u0RE8O0VWH3ocqychlUPy7CSG2vMhkj/F5d.q`

(as $password) along with:

`test@test.com` ($email).

I get those values in the function correctly.

 However after the update, i'm getting a different value in the password column:

`i1VjH4sRf5nqv3tnShnXNTSX57jRGnbZJt7w0VLX49nZdKRsRT`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
function updatePasswordInDatabase($password, $email) {
    require $mysql;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET Password = ? WHERE Email = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $password, $email);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Are you using PDO? Because that syntax is completely wrong. It looks like you are using `mysqli_*`.

Comment: Apologies, I meant mysqli indeed.

Comment: Is your password column `VARCHAR(255)`?

Comment: What are you using to hash passwords? It looks like `password_hash`? Show us any other code that code be involved.

Comment: @Dharman , the password column is VARCHAR(512)

Comment: @Script47 
Yes, it's $hashed_newpassword = password_hash($newpassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
The password is in the format it should be when delivered to the function

Comment: Show us where you function is being called from.

Comment: Do you have UTF8 connection set up? Is your column also `utf8mb4_unicode`?

Comment: @Dharman , yes it's an UTF8 connection. The column is utf8mb4, yes

Comment: $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
$hashed_newpassword = password_hash($newpassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare(Selecting Email & PW here);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $sessionid, $ip);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $email = $row['Email'];
    $passwordindatabase = $row['Password'];
    updatePasswordInDatabase($hashed_newpassword, $email);
}

Comment: Please add code to your question instead of in the comments. Then you can format it to be easier.to read, and you can fit all of it in. "Selecting Email & PW here" ...what SQL are you actually running here?